# Чи правильно вживати "стрічка" в значенні "рядок"?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Часто чую від програмістів слово *стрічка* в значенні *рядок*, наскільки це правильно? Сам я ставлюсь до цього як до суржиковості від російського слова *строчка*. На r2u знайшов [таке](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

У **Словарь росийсько-український** 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)

> **Строка́** = стрі́чка (С. Л.), рядо́к, сте́жка (С. Л.). — Цїлими місяцями
>   не міг написати нї одного рядка. Л. Н. В.

У **Словник українсько-російський** 1927р. (А. Ніковський) Вгору

> **Стрі́чка** –  1) лента;  2) тесемка;  3) строчка (в книге).

Comment: Думаю, програмісти просто користуються схожістю між **str**ing та **стр**ічка, плюс надлишок російськомовної термінології в галузі I.T. (**стр**ока). А взагалі — так, важка справа — шукати у словниках 1893 року термін, який позначає тип даних у комп'ютерному програмуванні. :)

Comment: Власне, я не розумію, навіщо для тексту два різні терміни для одного й того самого: `string` і `text`. Чому б не перекладати просто як «текст»? А якщо вже якесь середовище розрізняє `string` і `text` (он як в SQL є `CHAR(N)`, `VARCHAR(N)` і `TEXT`) — то конкретно для нього вже робити переклади, базуючись на відмінностях значень цих термінів саме в ньому.

Comment: @Sasha в українській мові наразі є *рядок* і *текст*. Не зовсім зрозумів ваш коментар.

Comment: @Yola, я не розумію, навіщо в українській, англійській чи будь-якій іншій мові декілька слів для позначення одного (на мій погляд) того самого. По-моєму, достатньо «text»=«текст». Все інше лише заплутує.

Comment: @Sasha так я не проти, я запитую чим *стрічка*, що я часто чую, відрізняється від *рядок*. Про текст я нічого не казав.

Comment: Потрібно спочатку визначитися з тим, що хочеться дізнатися. Якщо потрібна різниця між словами стрічка та рядок - то це одна справа. Коли ж потрібно підібрати слово в переклад, до абстрактного значення string з мови програмування - то це інша справа. string у використанні в мові програмування має своє пояснення, чому саме string, і від цього пояснення треба відштовхуватися. Слово string не пояснює усіх характеристик типу даних string. Можливо в українській мові є влучніше слово для обмеженої певним числом послідовності байтів (array), де кожен байт вважається елементом таблиці символів.

Comment: ... або два байти на один символ. Це вже залежить від кодування.

Comment: Слово стрічка не підходить для використання типу даних string, бо історично цей тип використовують лише для коротких рядків в тексті, можливо речення, можливо словосполучення, можливо слово, можливо будь яка невелика кількість слів. Невелика. Текст вже асоціюється з великою кількістю слів і відповідно з великим масивом байтів.

Answer (score 2):

#### «Стрічка» як еквівалент «string» (тип даних «масив символів»)

По-моєму, формально виправдане.

В «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах:

> **[СТРІ́ЧКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/strichka)**, и, *ж.*
>   <…>
>
> 3. *перен.* <…>
>
> // Ряд людей, машин і т. ін., вишикуваних в одну шеренгу, лінію, що стоять або рухаються.
>
> > *— Вистроїти в два ряди! — наказав гетьманець, і натовп почав лаштуватися, розтягаючись у довгу стрічку* (Іван Багмут, Опов., 1959, 21);
>
> // Ряди висаджених рослин.
>
> > *У ґрунтових теплицях розсаду висаджують стрічковим способом з відстанню між стрічками 60—70 см* (Овочівництво закритого і відкритого ґрунту, 1957, 56);
>
> <…>.

Хоча це значення й переносне, але чому «стрічка» не може позначати ряд **символів** (а не людей, машин, рослин)?

[image: Стрічка з літер «Мій␤т»]

Тим більше, що є такі слова, як «кінострічка» (тобто послідовність кадрів).

#### «Стрічка» як еквівалент «line»/«row» (рядок тексту без переносів)

[image: Рядок/лінія (line/row) — на противагу абзацу чи всьому тексту]
<sup>(Рисунок на основі [цього з Вікіпедії](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Plain_text.png) за ліцензією CC-BY-SA 3.0.)</sup>

По-моєму, в використання слова «стрічка» в цьому значенні теж формально виправдане, хоча й застаріле:

> **[СТРІ́ЧКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/strichka)**, и, *ж.*
>   <…>
>   6. *заст.* Рядок (у 2 знач.).
>
> > *Рука несамовито бігає, виводячи стрічку за стрічкою* (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 150);
> >     *Хоцінський розгорнув листок газети і почав водити очима за стрічками* (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 133);
> >     *Знову без передишки швидко поповзла довга, рівна стрічка слів...* (Олесь Донченко, V, 1957, 552).
>
> ---
>
> **[РЯДО́К](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjadok)**, дка́, *ч.* <…> 2. Кілька слів, літер або інших знаків, написаних чи надрукованих в одну лінію. <…>

#### Висновки

Я не знаю, наскільки має сенс використовувати «стрічку» в значенні «string» (тип даних) або «line»/«row» (рядок тексту). Але обидва використання формально можуть бути обґрунтовані.

Також припускаю, що хтось може використовувати як відповідник до «string» не «рядок», а саме «стрічку», щоб уникнути натяків на «рядок» у значенні «line»/«row».

Comment: Перша частина відповіді завершується *Хоча це значення й переносне, але чому «стрічка» не може позначати ряд символів (а не людей, машин, рослин)?*, відповідь проста, тому що він і не позначає ряд чогось, він позначає геометричну фігуру, наприклад кінострічка має носій у вигляді стрічки.

Comment: У другій частині стрічка в наведених уривках знов-таки має значення типографського/геометричного об'єкта - лінії тексту.

Comment: @Yola, в другій частині я сам проти використання «стрічка» у значенні «line/row». А от у першій — використання «стрічка» замість «string» мені здається цілком виправданим — в англійській «string» теж позначає стрічку, мотузку, струну, а не ряд, і мені здається, що використати «стрічка», щоб чітко відрізники від «line/row» (який уже «рядок») — гарна ідея.

Answer (score 2):

«Стрічка» в значенні «рядок тексту» вважалося застарілим вже, принаймні, в часи СУМ-11 (70-ті рр. ХХ ст.).

> **6.** *заст.* Рядок (у 2 знач.). Рука несамовито бігає, виводячи стрічку за стрічкою (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 150); Хоцінський розгорнув листок газети і почав водити очима за стрічками (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 133); Знову без передишки швидко поповзла довга, рівна стрічка слів... (Олесь Донченко, V, 1957, 552).
>
> <sub>Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 782.</sub>

Здається, в цьому текстовому значенні його не вживали аж до недавніх часів, коли воно звідкись виринуло в мові програмістів. Припускаю, що воскресінню цього значення посприяла схожість з рос. «строчка», брак україномовної галузевої літератури та жахлива українська мова викладачів технічних спеціальностей (які ще на початку нульових читали лекції російською).

Comment: Хочу нагадати, що СУМ-11 — [совєцьких часїв](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85). Там [могли](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B4) помічати звичнї слова або дїялективними, або полонїзмами, або застарілими чи щось на штиб. А теперішня лїнґвистика така собі, якщо чесно, ба навіть не дуже змінилася за всі цї часи.

Comment: У даному випадку, йдеться про застарілість не слова «стрічка», а одного з його значень. Тоді як інше значення зберігалось (те, що на Вашому суржику звучить як «лєнта», літературною українською мовою називається «стрічка»).

Comment: До речі, а хіба желехівкою не правильнїше буде «звичні» (бо «звичний»)? Чи в Вашому варіянтї вимовляється «звичнїй», і від нього «звичнї»?